# Access google drive shared links using Google Drive REST API v3

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-api

I'm developing an Android app that needs to deliver files stored in my Google Drive account to the users.

I tried to do the file access with Google Drive API REST v3, I've checked the documentation provided by Google but i didn't find any information on how to access public files or shared links via the API, so any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try it too, but shared files came visible after opening them in google drive interface...

I don't know how do this automaticaly...

[Try to view all shared files, but shows only opened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775449/try-to-view-all-shared-files-but-shows-only-opened-before)

[How to get the link of a publicly shared file/folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434339/how-to-get-the-link-of-a-publicly-shared-file-folder?rq=1)